# How can I `pg_dump` the entire schema and the data from **some** tables?

Tags: postgresql

How can I dump the entire schema from a PostgreSQL database and the data from a subset of the tables?

`pg_dump -s my_database -t table_1 -t table_2 > output.sql` seems to ignore the `-t` flags and dumps only the schema.

Comment: Omit the -s flag. (-s is "schema-only")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pg_dump -s my_database > output.sql
pg_dump -a -t table_1 -t table_2 >> output.sql
```